# child div with border radius shows color of parent div at borders

Tags: css

I have 2 divs, one is parent and 2nd is child div as follows

```css
.outer{
    background: #211182;
    height: 50px;
}

.inner{
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 60px 0 0 0;
    background: #f9f9f9
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

only child div has border-radius.
it shows parent background color at border of child div which is not expected.
I tried `overflow: hidden` , also tried `border : none` and `border-width : 0` and `width : 100%; height:100%` but no luck.
please help me to resolve this.
Attaching screenshot of the result.
[image]

Comment: I don't see the problem here, the purple is your parent div, it appears because the child is not hiding the parent due to the curve

Comment: apply the radius to the parent

Comment: @Xanthous my requirement is to show purple cure on top left corner on grey color,  but border color is not required.

Comment: @TemaniAfif what should be parent's radius if parent needs to be rectangular.

Comment: Cannot reproduce as you provided in the screenshot.

Comment: @iftikharyk you can reproduce it by trying to test it in mobile view in browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. Can you tell me the specific screen size and browser on which you are seeing this issue?

Comment: @iftikharyk on chrome browser for iphone 6/7/8 plus device on 50% zoom i.e 414 X 736
Unfortunately it does not shows in this code snippet, but if you create a file and run it separately you can find it.